# How to avoid `index exceeds maxCellCount` when deleting an item at the scrolled bottom of a combobox?

Tags: javafx, combobox

In JavaFX I use a `ComboBox` containing a `New...` item that allows to create a new entry. Once it is created and selected, a `Delete` button allows to remove it.

Adding the item, then scrolling to it in the `ComboBox` and finally clicking the `Delete` button shows the following message:

```
janv. 04, 2016 2:25:01 PM com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$2$1
```

If I do not scroll to the item, it doesn't show this message when it is deleted.
Is there anyway I can avoid this output ? I tried to find a way to scroll back up but failed.

**EDIT** I currently removed that error using a listener to adapt the visible row count. Although that will probably cause me trouble if the list grows too big:

```
list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(baseElements());
list.add("New...");
list.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) change -> combo.setVisibleRowCount(change.getList().size()));

combo.setItems(list);
```

That removes any scroll as the combo will grow depending on it's contents and thus the error cannot occur anymore. That's not what I expect for a solution though.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? What JDK version are you using?

Comment: I'm using JDK 8u66. I'll try to find some time to a a MC&V example

Answer (score 0):

Have hou tried reseting the actual item in the combo box before deleting it with something like the code below?

```
Object value = combo.getValue();
combo.setValue(null);
combo.getItems().remove(value);
```

Comment: Yes I tried your way and with `combo.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()`. Nothing seems to work.